# PHP Collect framework equivalent in Python

Tags: python

I am looking at the equivalent of PHP Laravel collect framework in Python.

Note i am not looking at the Laravel equivalent in Python.

The Laravel collection framework converts things into collection 
and then provides methods to manipulate those collection using a nice 
fluent framework.

```
$collection = collect(['taylor', 'abigail', null])
    ->map(function ($name) {
    return strtoupper($name);
})
   ->reject(function ($name) {
    return empty($name);
});
```

In the above example the collect function turns the PHP Array into a Laravel collection.

Then the map function fluently using -> maps each element to uppercase and then another method is chained on to reject empty Names i.e Null and the output is

TAYLOR and ABIGAIL

I saw iter_tools and more_itertools which is kind of close but does not have a fluent API.

Is there anything else that can wet my appetite ?

Comment: I think they should have commented if they downvoted... I'm not familiar with Laravel.  It could be useful to show some example code of what you have and what you're trying to get to.   What exactly do you mean by "collection"?

Comment: Thanks i will add an example

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest thing I've seen to Laravel collect in Python:  https://github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional

```
from functional import seq

seq(1, 2, 3, 4)\
    .map(lambda x: x * 2)\
    .filter(lambda x: x > 4)\
    .reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
# 14

# or if you don't like backslash continuation
(seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .map(lambda x: x * 2)
    .filter(lambda x: x > 4)
    .reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
)
# 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform basic `map`, `filter`, etc using builtin python functions.

```
namesArr = ['taylor', 'abigail', None]
filtered = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), namesArr)
upperCaseArr = map(lambda x: x.upper(), filtered)
print(list(upperCaseArr)) # note the list() here
# ['TAYLOR', 'ABIGAIL']
```

Another option is to use something like [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) DataFrames. Pandas is everything but the kitchen sink. It's a well supported, very powerful library that is easy to get lost in.

Comment: This does what is required but the fluent syntax is missing i think no ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from streamable import Stream

# lazy operations
collection: Stream[str] = (
    Stream(lambda: ["taylor", "abigail", None])
    .filter()
    .map(str.upper)
)

print(list(collection))
```

```
['TAYLOR', 'ABIGAIL']
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...